# How to Calculate All The Gradients of the Curves of a Graph

Tags: javascript, math, graph

I haven't seen an exact answer to this anywhere. I'm generating financial graph data. The data points could generate curves, lines, sharp points etc.

I'm trying to develop an algorithm whereby I can determine up trends, sideways trends, and down trends from the gradients of the graph. For instance, if the gradient between three sets of sequential data points is of a similar value, we have a consistent trend.

I can obviously calculate the grade/gradient as a percentage with (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) but the y-axis is just minutes/hrs/days, and the x values could be quite large or small so there needs to be some sort of normalisation to keep the gradients of the various graphs between, say, 0 to 100 and 0 to -100 (for a downward slope), where 0 would be a horizontal gradient.

I feel like I would need to calculate and recalculate gradients based on similar previous gradients and would need to do a decent amount of calculations to determine one consistent similar uptrend for, say, 10 data points.

Surely this problem has already been solved or there is some sort of quick approximation that can be made so I can at least determine data points that have a similar gradient?

Oh, also, I'm doing all this in JavaScript but am using Decimal.js which seems pretty accurate, so I know my data points are valid.

Thanks ahead of time!
Ged

Comment: Uhhh, this question is very much about programming. Floating-point math in Javascript (and indeed any programming language) can be dicey so I'm asking about best practises and possible pre-existing libraries that might help, outside of using Decimal.

I feel like that's pretty apparent since I posted it in a programming forum.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to accomplish is simple the [first-order derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) from a set of points. The more points you have the better. If you only want gradient between 2 points is actually delta Y over delta X: `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. This gives you a slope, something like change of $USD/min. That's usually a good metric to have.

But if you want to normalize it you can convert to degrees, something like `tan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))`, and then just normalize to 0-90 degrees.

`100 / 90 * tan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))`

Comment: Thanks for that. It's been years since I've studied derivatives, integration and the like so I'll have to hit up some of my first year uni math :)

The reason why I think I can't use a simple delta (which I stuffed up explaining above) is because the x-axis is somewhat arbitrary. Each interval has a value of 1 basic time unit, basically, unless I convert to second, minutes, hours etc. Proportionally, whether I do that conversion or not, I should get the same gradient value whether I'm using seconds, minutes, hours, elephants, whatever. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ohhh, yes, the normalising works great, thanks you! I should have gone back to good ol SOHCAHTOA.